# Replace comma's with dots on opening google spreadsheet

Tags: replace, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have a questionaire that fills a google spreadsheet.

When I open the spreadsheet I want all commas (,) to be replaced by dots (.).

The name of my spreadsheet is 'GF Answers' and the sheet that it contains is 'responses'.

Any directions/suggestions for appropriate code?

Thanks!

Comment: Write a Google Apps Script with an `onOpen` trigger that opens the Spreadsheet, gets it entire range, all the values of the range, loop trough the columns and rown replacing commas with dots in the variable that came with the getValues method, then `setValues` this variable. That's not even a direction, that's an entire map.

Answer (score 1):

To take Kriggs answer one step further, and simply drop you off at the destination, something like the following should work (you may have to change the 'range' to conform to your spreadsheet if there are any sections you don't want to modify):

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('responses');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()); 
  var data  = range.getValues();

  for (var row=0; row<data.length; row++) {
    for (var item=0; item<data[row].length; item++) {
      data[row][item] = data[row][item].replace(/,/g, '.');
    }
  }
  range.setValues(data);
}
```